# Starting Dash Space Pattern with space instead of dash in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, markers

I need to create a simple line symbol which starts with a gap (space) instead of a dash. I avoid replacing the simple line with a marker line because of the x-axis offset that i need to introduce. Can be created an expression to realise this type of dash pattern?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom dash pattern composed of two entries.

Start with 0 dash and 5 spaces, then 2 dash and 0 spaces (use the dash/space length you want, the 0 are the important entries)

[image]